# Как работают подготовленные запросы изнутри?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, безопасность, preparedstatement

Знаю, что есть такая вещь как подготовленные запросы.
Например в `PDO` *PHP* можно быть увереным, что никаких SQL инъекций случиться не может если писать например:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_table` (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $value);        
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

Я понимаю, что это всё, по факту, вызывает методы `PREPARE` и `EXECUTE` самой БД, но я не смог правильно составить запрос в поиске о том, **почему** это работает? То есть понятно, что запрос как бы сохраняется в кеше и туда подставляются данные. Но, они же подставляются в итоге. Почему это безопасно? Почему инъекция в этом случае невозможна? Все переменные (плейсхолдеры) в итоге в БД обрабатываются специальными функциями как только им говорят `prepare`?

Comment: Открой эксель. Положи в А1 значение `aaa'@par1'bbb`. Положи в А2  значение `aaa'@par2'bbb`. Выполни поиск/замену `@par1` на `ccc'ddd`. Выполни текст по столбцам по одинарной кавычке. Выполни поиск/замену `@par2` на `ccc'ddd`. Результат - разный... Вот первое - это прямая подстановка в запрос, а второе - подстановка в подготовленный запрос.

Comment: В первом случае последовательность (подставить - распарсить - выполнить). Во втором (распарсить - подставить - выполнить).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть всех инъекций - подстановка лишних кавычек. Давайте определим, зачем вообще нужны кавычки в запросе. Когда вы передаете текст запроса `select * from tab where x='abc'` серверу, первым делом в дело вступает синтаксический анализатор, который превращает принятый текст в понятный машине вид. На этом этапе анализатору надо найти все ключевые слова, определить где и какие используются имена таблиц и колонок БД, а где стоят константы. Если условие выглядит `x=563`, то на этапе лексического разбора константу сразу видно, потому, что она начинается с цифры, а имена объектов БД (не заключенные в обратные апострофы) с цифр начинаться не могут. Но в случае `x=abc` понять что такое `abc` имя колонки или константа анализатор не может. Для этого и придуманы кавычки, они подсказывают анализатору, что вот тут началась константа. Метод prepare обычно работает на уровне драйвера БД и самого сервера БД. Именно тот текст, который вы ему передали проходит стадию синтаксического разбора. Итогом которого является некое дерево выполнения, выраженное в виде структур данных, понятных исполнителю. И в этом дереве просто известно, что вот в этом узле надо будет подставить константу, когда она будет получена при execute. Все, что передается при execute, приходит в него отдельными параметрами, лексического и синтаксического разбора этих параметров не требуется. Соответственно никаких специальных обозначений "это константа" то же не нужно. А раз не надо никак обозначать константы, то и подставить лишние кавычки просто некуда, любые кавычки будут восприняты как часть данных.

Comment: Спасибо. В голове картинка сложилась.